# Ignore certain properties in an interface while creating an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have interface defined with some properties. I want to create an object from this interface, however while creating I don't want to fully initialize all the properties mentioned in the interface. I just want to initialize few. How can I achieve that? Thank you.

```
export interface Campaign {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  createdOn: string;
  lastUpdated: string;
  createdBy: User;
  type: CampaignType;
  status: CampaignStatus;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  budget: number;
  description: string;
  account: Account;
}
```

i want to create an array of campaign objects.
this is what i am trying to do .

```
let campaigns: Campaign[] = [
    {  id:"1",
       name: "test campaign"
      }

   ];
```

however i get the following error .

Type '{ id: string; name: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Campaign': createdOn, lastUpdated, createdBy, type, and 6 more.ts(2740)

Comment: But why? If an object implements interface `X` then I'm expecting it to have all properties and methods defined by interface `X`. Why else would I use an interface at all?

Comment: this is just for testing .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use Partial -

```
let campaigns: Partial<Campaign>[] = [
    {  id:"1",
       name: "test campaign"
      }

   ];
```

Comment: ok this is cool, loving TS for its "just the right amount of typing" approach -- I don't always need all 8 properties in APIGatewayProxyEvent (for a test for instance)

Comment: For those interested, here is a link to the documentation of all the utility types. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Answer (score 8):

if you make the optional properties nullable it should work.

example:

```
type User = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName?: string;
};

// We can assign a string to the "lastName" property
let john: User = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" };

// ... or we can explicitly assign the value undefined
let jane: User = { firstName: "Jane", lastName: undefined };

// ... or we can not define the property at all
let jake: User = { firstName: "Jake" };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could mark the properties that you don't want to set a value on creation as optional by doing `{ propName?: propType }`

or if want to mark all the properties to be optional, you could use `Partial`

```
Partial<{
  prop1: string,
  prop2: number,
}>
```